# Anchor Tag with URL still redirects to subdirectory

Tags: html, css, reactjs, anchor

having some trouble with the anchor tag not opening in a new tab even with `target="_blank"` and the protocol specified in the `href`. Consider the following:

Current URL: `https://x.y1.com:9443/app/help/wf/en-us/Content/topics/workflows/function-reference/object/object_process.htm`

I have the following HTML tag:

```
<a 
  class="MCPopupThumbnailLink MCPopupThumbnailPopup" 
  href="https://z.y.com/wf/en-us/Content/resources/images/workflows/object-map-list.png"
  target="_blank"
  rel="noopener noreferrer"
>
   <img 
     class="MCPopupThumbnail img imgthumbnail"
     data-mc-width="346"
     data-mc-height="582"
     src="https://z.y.com/wf/en-us/Content/resources/images/workflows/object-map-list_thumb_220_220.png" 
     tabindex="">
</a>
```

I expected when I clicked on the image, I would get a new tab with the URL being `https://z.y.com/wf/en-us/Content/resources/images/workflows/object-map-list.png`.

Instead, in the ***same*** tab, I am directed to `https://x.y1.com:9443/app/help/wf/en-us/Content/resources/images/workflows/object-map-list.png`, as if I used a relative path for my `href`, which, in the context of my app, that route doesn't exist.

Setting the `href` to something like `https://google.com` works just fine here. What's going on here?

Comment: The problem is browser store the old cached and your code is not updated . Try to clear cache and data of your browser

Comment: The code you have given works fine (with images I have chosen) so the problem is not currently reproducible. Please create a runnable snippet which demonstrates the problem. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example